# Why is div width rendered so differently on IE & FF in contrast to Chrome, Opera, & Safari?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

On [saveadullam.org/pages/media.html](http://saveadullam.org/pages/media.html), the main text section correctly covers the full width in Chrome, Safari, and Opera. But in IE7 and FF3, it only covers 2/3 of the width.  See images. The bilingual text is in a table, which I know is taboo, but the problem here is in a div that holds the whole table, and not within a table-based layout

I know that IE has its rendering problems, but here IE and FF misbehave the same way. (The stylesheet is [here](http://saveadullam.org/stylesheet/adullam.css).)

What is the problem?

(Edit: Solved for FF, but not for IE.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove width:70% from .mainBody from css. It works on FF.

```
.mainBody {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Right-o, that did the trick on FF -- but not on IE. I actually created a different class mainBodyMedia without the width:70% since the mainBody class is needed elsewhere with width:70% . Any ideas about why it rendered at full-width in WebKit? Anyway, the problem is solved in FF -- but can you figure out why it still exists in IE7?

Comment: Yep, the issue is that you have a single cell in a row and the cell is set to `width: 70%`.  Seems like different UAs treat this differently.  Of course the CSS spec doesn't actually define the behavior here....  Note that you still have the `70%` style on `.mainBodyMedia`.

Comment: Thank you, Boris. This is helpful.

Comment: @Boris Strangely enough, the fix solved the problem  in FF even though, as you correctly say, this new class .mainBodyMeda  still had 70% width. But after deleting that, the problem is resolved.